# textbox not accepting pop up window value

Tags: php, html

I have one text-box ,when i click on it popup window gets open ,but value is not inserted in text-box when i select any radio option in popup,where is the problem?
this is textbox

```
    <tr><td> Work </td>
                <td><input title="Enter Work You Want to search ." readonly="readonly" id="search_workind" name="search_workind" type="text" size="20"  onclick="javascript:opendrop()">                
</td></tr>
```

this calling function

```
function opendrop()
{
var popy= window.open('search_kind.php','popup_form','width=380 height=300 left=800 top=300');
}
```

this is search_kind.php

```
<?php ob_start() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Search </title>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function validepopupform()
{
    window.opener.document.getElementById('search_workind').value=" " 
//self.close();

} 
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form  id="popupform" name="popupform">
<h3>Audit and Assurance</h3>
<input name="kind" type="radio" id="kind" value="A" onclick="javascript:validepopupform()" />A
<br/>
<input name="kind" type="radio" id="kind" value="B" onclick="validepopupform()" />B
<br/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
<?php ob_flush() ?>
```

Comment: Can you please show us your full code for this?

Comment: i have edited text-box full code

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the text box data onclick; in search_kind.php 
add a submit button,
 then

```
<td><input title="Enter Work You Want to search ." readonly="readonly" id="search_workind" name="search_workind" type="text" size="20"  onclick="javascript:opendrop()"> value=$_POST['kind']
```

Comment: can't i do it just by clicking on radio option? because i dont want user to click twice

Comment: no. if it was in the same page then we could done that. BUt you are using a popup

Comment: did you add form action?? and call the .php where the textbox is??

Comment: <form  id="popupform" name="popupform" action="pagecontainingtexbox" method="post">

Comment: using this pagecontainingtextbox is getting open in popup window

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21717/discussion-between-ganeshrj-and-raj)